# Use Composer module in PHP file

Tags: php, composer-php, xss

I want to use the following [AntiXSS library](https://github.com/voku/anti-xss) in one PHP file. It is my first time using Composer, but I followed their installation steps and I installed it successfully. I downloaded the library through Composer, updated it and Composer created the `vendor/` folder in my directory with the necessary files.

Now I added the following `require 'vendor/autoload.php'` into my PHP file. I created a new AntiXSS class but I obtain the following error:

> `Class AntiXSS` not found in my directory on line 3.

I tried to use an absolute path instead of `vendor/autoload.php` but it isn't working yet and I don't know if I should do something more.
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class is located in the `voku\helper` namespace. Use `new \voku\helper\AntiXSS()` to instantiate it or use `use` imports to import the namespace.

See [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php) for more information about namespaces.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I never heard about namespaces before, thanks for tell me! I tested it and works like a charm! :)